# Group by timestamp and response code in humio/falcon logscale

Tags: falcon, humio

I am trying to query the count of transactions per response code per hour.
Following is the query i've been using
|parseJson()|path="/ra" |formatTime("%Y/%m/%d %H", field=@timestamp, locale=en_US, timezone=Z, as="DateTime") |groupBy([DateTime,"resp-code"])

However, I need the data in the following format,

Date/Hour in rows
2XX, 4XX, 5XX in columns